# How to link JavaScript and HTML5 pages without <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a button for my webpage that changes the ENTIRE colour palette of the page with Code.org AppLab. The only problem is, code.org doesn't allow the use of the `<script>` tag for "security reasons". As far as I know the only way I can turn on CSS settings with a button is with `getElementById()`. If anyone knows how to activate CSS settings when a button is clicked without JS, how to link external JS files to an html file, or use inline JS all WITHOUT the use of the `<script>` tag please show me how.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I recommend all new users visit [ask] and take the [tour] for tips on how to form a question that best enables the community to assist you.  The specific nature of your issue is unclear.  Can you provide a [mcve] that illustrates the issue?  Can you provide the complete requirements of your use case?  Can you show what you have tried so far?  Remember, without sufficient detail, the community is limited in how they can provide assistance.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: If they do not allow <script> tag, you will have to take your code somewhere else.

Comment: FWIW, I would say there's a 50% chance this *is* possible, but I'd need to understand more about your situation.

Comment: You have two separate issues. 1) How to write the code and 2) How to use the code in that environment. You should be able to research #2 through their documentation. For #1 you will need to provide some sample html with a far more detailed explanation of how this color palete is expected to work. Quite frankly it sounds like you need to hire a developer. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service

Comment: @KrystalPotato 101, I think you are looking for XSS, then you must use `a href` with or without `onclick`, for example, `<a href="" onclick="document.write('Here is JavaScript code');">`.

Comment: Are you trying to build a browser extension or something?

Comment: You can put the code in an element's onclick attribute, e.g. `<div onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'">Click me</div>`.

Comment: Thank you to everyone, who helped, your answers helped me solve this problem, and now I can use this in the future. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML attributes. It may be blocked as well, but it's worth giving a try. See this example:

```html
<!--It's not necessary, but it'd be easy to put all your scripts inside a template tag or the like-->
<template id="script" style="display:none">
alert("Hello, world! JavaScript has been injected");
document.getElementById("btn").style.cssText = `
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
`;
</template>
<button id="btn" onclick="(Function(document.getElementById('script').innerHTML))()">Inject JavaScript</button>
```

A similar approach to the above is to inject a script tag:

```html
<!--It's not necessary, but it'd be easy to put all your scripts inside a template tag or the like-->
<template id="script" style="display:none">
alert("Hello, world! JavaScript has been injected");
document.getElementById("btn").style.cssText = `
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
`;
</template>
<button id="btn" onclick="const s=document.createElement('script');s.innerHTML=document.getElementById('script').innerHTML;document.body.appendChild(s);">Inject JavaScript</button>
```

If all else fails, you could also use an `<a>` tag and execute JavaScript as a URL (this example won't work when you're running it on StackOverflow due to their whatever):

```html
<!--It's not necessary, but it'd be easy to put all your scripts inside a template tag or the like-->
<template id="script" style="display:none">
alert("Hello, world! JavaScript has been injected");
document.getElementById("btn").style.cssText = `
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: none;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
`;
</template>
<!--Prefix JavaScript URLs with "javascript:"-->
<a href="javascript:(Function(document.getElementById('script').innerHTML))()" id="btn">Inject JavaScript</a>
```

Comment: Hmm, if they don't allow script elements, they're not going to look kindly on use of the [*Function* constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function) (which is akin to [*eval*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)). Far better to just put the code in the button's *onclick* attribute.

Comment: @RobG If Code.org really doesn't want you to run JavaScript, attribute handlers like `onclick` won't work either. You could also just use the URL.